# What is the reason of getting model of an object in apache wicket?

Tags: java, model, wicket

I am new in apache wicket and I don't understand why we get the model of an object. For example, we get a model of our Class Movie at form component in web page in order to save the submitted inputs;

```
CompoundPropertyModel model = new CompoundPropertyModel(movie);
      this.setModel(model);
      this.add(new TextField("title"));
      this.add(new TextField("year"));
```

And the code continues;

```
@Override
public void onSubmit() {
    Movie movie = (Movie) this.getModelObject();
    WicketApplication app = (WicketApplication) this.getApplication();
    MovieCollection collection = app.getCollection();
    collection.addMovie(movie);
    this.setResponsePage(new MovieDisplayPage(movie));
}
```

Comment: I think you answered the question with your example: the textfields dont need to know anything about how the information gets saved, they just use the compoundpropertymodel. For more information about wicket models read: http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/modelsforms.html

Comment: So we get the model of the form components to the class and somehow we match their data. I guess I understand. Thank you for your comment and link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CompoundPropertyModel` is a controversial model to say the least. It appears to work like magic, and has some unforeseen semantics with it.

The JavaDoc of the `CompoundPropertyModel` tells it all really:

```java
/**
 * A simple compound model which uses the component's name as the property expression to retrieve
 * properties on the nested model object.
 * 
 * CompoundPropertyModel is a chaining model so it will call get/setobject on the given object if
 * the object is an instanceof IModel itself.
 * 
 * @see org.apache.wicket.model.IModel
 * @see org.apache.wicket.model.Model
 * @see org.apache.wicket.model.LoadableDetachableModel
 * @see IChainingModel
 * 
 * @author Jonathan Locke
 * 
 * @param <T>
 *            The model object type
 */
public class CompoundPropertyModel<T> extends ChainingModel<T> implements IComponentInheritedModel<T>
```

The magic sits in the resolution of the property paths. A `TextField` with a `null` model will look up the component hierarchy to see if there's a parent with a `IComponentInheritedModel` (which CompoundPropertyModel implements). If so, it will use that to evaluate the component identifier as a property expression based from the root of the CompoundPropertyModel's (inner-most) object.

This way you can do things like:

```java
setModel(new CompoundPropertyModel(person));
add(new TextField("spouse.familyName"));
add(new TextField("children[0].age"));
```

Quite neat, but also considered magic.

The danger lies in the following piece of code:

```java
setModel(new CompoundPropertyModel(person));
add(new TextField("spouse.familyName"));
add(new TextField("children[0].age"));
add(new Link<Person>("delete") {
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        Person p = getModelObject();
        if(p.isUnderage()) {
            p.delete();
        }
    }
});
```

When the link retrieves its model object, it will trigger the `delete()` method of the Person prior to the under age check. So be careful with CompoundPropertyModel.